# Powers of Sine/Cosine Integral Proof and connection to Fourier Convergence Guidance

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on ℝ satisfying $f(x+2\pi) = f(x)$ , If $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos^n(x)\,dx = 0$$ for all $n \ge 0$ and $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \sin^n(x)\,dx = 0$$ for all $n \ge 1$ then does it follow than $f = 0$? Prove your answer.

I'm really stuck on how to prove this. 
I know that it's false that $f = 0$ , given that the conditions given to me say that $f$ is a periodic function , so like $f$ could be another trig function and it would still equal zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is periodic with $T_0 = 2\pi$, the Fourier series
$$f(t) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(n t) + b_n\sin(n t)$$

At $n = 0$, the integral (up to a constant) is that of evaluating the DC component $a_0$, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t) dt = a_0 = 0$$
Similarly, at $n = 1$, both $a_1, b_1 = 0$. At $n = 2$, $$\frac{2}{T_0}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\cos^2(t) dt = \frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t) dt + \frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t) \cos(2x)) = a_0 +  \frac{a_2}{2} = 0$$

But $a_0 = 0$, hence $a_2 = 0$.

**Proceed inductively**

The [expansion of $\cos^n, \sin^n$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html) is in terms of harmonics. And since the fourier coefficients $a_{i}, b_{i}$ are zero for all $i < n$. It follows that $a_n, b_n = 0$ by linearity of integration.

Comment: But what if $f \neq 0$ , wouldn't the integrals still equal 0, like if $f = \sin(x)\cos(x)$ which is still periodic under those condition, then the integrals would still equal 0 , and in that case $f \neq 0$ or am I misreading the question?

Comment: Ah, now I see. The question is phrased ambiguously so that $f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$ need not be its period. In that case, it's pointless to use a tool like Fourier series here. I think your counterexample is a suitable answer to the question.

Comment: I tried using the complex forms of sin and cos to come up with something, but so far no luck. Well in terms of hints, my professor told me it might have something to do with convergence of fourier terms. So your explanation above might be on the right track.

Comment: Do you think you could help me on a problem dealing with Jacobians? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522052/jacobians-and-their-vector-coordinates